# Adding a certificate to Store then retrieve it

Tags: c#, windows, rsa, x509certificate2

Disclaimer: I am 2 days into reading about Certificates/RSA Algorithms and Encrypt/Decrypt.

I am trying to do a small app that communicates with Windows Key Store ( Certificate Store ) and where I should be able to read certificates/add certificates.

I have created a method to add a certificate.

```
 public void AddKey()
    {
        CngKey cngKey;

        CngKeyCreationParameters cng = new CngKeyCreationParameters
        {
            KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages
        };


        if (!CngKey.Exists(KEY_NAME))
        {
            cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, KEY_NAME, cng);
        }
        else
        {
            cngKey = CngKey.Open(KEY_NAME);
        }

        RSACng rsaKey = new RSACng(cngKey)
        {
            KeySize = 2048
        };

        byte[] rsaPrvKeyExport = rsaKey.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob);
        byte[] rsaPubKeyExport = rsaKey.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);

        CngKey cngPrv = CngKey.Import(rsaPrvKeyExport, CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob);
        CngKey cngPub = CngKey.Import(rsaPubKeyExport, CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);

        //var signed = Sign512(Constants.STRING_TO_ENCODE.ToByteArray(), rsaPrvKeyExport);

        string exportPrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey());

        string pemString = $"{Constants.RSA_KEY_HEADER}\n{exportPrivateKey}\n{Constants.RSA_KEY_FOOTER}";

        

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        var certificate = BuildSelfSignedServerCertificate(rsaKey);
        var thumbprint = certificate.Thumbprint;

        store.Certificates.Add(certificate);
        store.Close();
```

}

I know not all lines in this code are needed, but I am in the learning process.

So what I do here is create a cngKey
Open the store.
Create a Certificate from my cngKey
Add the certificate to the store
Close the store.

I generate a certificate from a cngKey using this code

```
 private X509Certificate2 BuildSelfSignedServerCertificate(RSA key)
        {           

            X500DistinguishedName distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={Constants.CERTIFICATE_NAME}");


            var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, key, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));


            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
               new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                   new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

            //request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

            var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3650)));
            certificate.FriendlyName = Constants.CERTIFICATE_NAME;

            return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "WeNeedASaf3rPassword"), "WeNeedASaf3rPassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        }
```

This gives no error, but when I open the certificate store I can't find it

[image]

I also tried to retrive it programmaticaly

using this bit of code

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            var certificates = store.Certificates;
```

but my certificate is not here.

What am I missing, I am sure I am doing something wrong, but being new to this, I have no idea what.

Online I could not find a complete example of what I tried to achieve here.

Comment: You appear to be using store.Certificates.Add; have you tried store.Add? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.add

Comment: P.S., I think you might have a slight memory leak in there. X509Store implements IDisposable, but you don't have any `using` statements or Dispose() calls.

Comment: @dimitar.bogdanov thank you, indeed that was the problem. I have many problems in my code, as soon as I figure out how to use the Store/Certificates/Keys I will refactor everything. Doing store.Add(certificate), allows me now to see the certificate when doing store.Certifacates, but I still can't see it in windows interface under "Personal"

Comment: you are looking in wrong store in MMC. You have to look in machine store (`certlm.msc`), not in current user store.

Comment: If you're trying to use persisted keys, don't set the KeySize property.  If you set it to the value it is, nothing happens.  If you set it to a new value, then the object disconnects from the stored key and moves to a new ephemeral one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dimitar.bogdanov pointed out in comments, you are not adding the certificate to the store:

```
store.Certificates.Add(certificate);
```

here you are adding the certificate only to disconnected collection. Any changes in this collection object will not reflect actual store state. Instead, you have to use [X509Store.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.add) method to update actual store.